# SmartScreen блокирует запуск установщика приложения

Tags: безопасность, установка, вирусы, inno-setup

Нубский вопрос наверно, но может что то можно сделать, чтоб не блокировало, там же вирусов нет. Я сделал установщик своего приложения с помощью `InnoSetup` но установку приложения блокирует `Smart Screen` - пишет:

> Система Windows защитила ваш компьютер
>
> Фильтр SmartScreen Защитника Windows предотвратил запуск неопознанного приложения, которое может подвергнуть компьютер риску.
>
> Издатель: 
> Неизвестный издатель

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Использовать последнею версию Inno-Setup
2. Подписать файл установки электронной подписью уровня Code Signing.
3. Проверить на реакцию антивирусов на [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/).
4. Набрать популярность. Попросить сообщество принудительно устанавливать.

Самое действенное будет выполнение пункта 2, так как в последствии не будет возможности вставить вирус в ваш инсталлятор.